# Android Transitions between Activities in Activity Group

Tags: android

I am trying to animate between Activities within an Activity Group.

I know the purists will tell me I shouldn't use multiple activities and should be using a View Flipper, but I didn't start the project and don't have the option to completely re-implement the solution.

The problem is instead of the new activity sliding over the top of the previous, the previous is cleared and the new activity slides over a blank background.

Is there anyway to keep the previous activity in view until the new activity has animated?

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent, AnimationType animationType){
    Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));


final View view = window != null ? window.getDecorView() : null;
    if (view != null) {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slideup);
    view.startAnimation(animation);
    this.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```